# Add custom attributes to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am adding a custom property to an XMLHttpRequest, like so:

```
function respond() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        alert(this.testParam);
    }
}

var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.onreadystatechange = respond;
req.testParam = "yes";
req.open('get', '/', true);
req.send();
```

This works in Google Chrome, but is it considered good practice? I think the XMLHttpRequest is a native object, and I have heard bad things can happen.

I put a fiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/3bTVC/

Comment: It should be fine, so long as you don't need a property that `XMLHttpRequest` is already using. And, the concerns with extending host objects generally regard trying to modify their `prototype`. Host objects are often defined through interfaces rather than concrete types and inheritance can be inconsistent between engines. [Juriy Zaytsev has a good write-up about it.](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/)

Comment: So far as I understand it, XMLHttpRequest is a host object and not a native Javascript object (i.e. it is DOM-like, not Object-like). However, your point about modifying the object vs the prototype is a good one. I personally haven't had issues with adding arbitrary properties straight onto DOM elements.

Comment: Yeah, `XMLHttpRequest` instances are host objects. That is, objects, types, etc. that are defined for a specific environment. In this case, [by the W3C for client-side web development](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/). "*Native*" are those [defined for the language itself](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).